# What happens to docker volumes created by container when the container is stopped

Tags: docker, docker-volume

This is my Dockerfile for an spring boot app

```
FROM openjdk:8u151-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
ADD target/classes/application.properties /workdir/application.properties
ADD target/foo-app-2.0.0.jar /workdir/app.jar
WORKDIR /workdir
ENV JAVA_OPTS=""
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "java $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar app.jar" ]
```

It creates a volume `/tmp` when the container is started which is stored in `/var/lib/docker` folder of the host.

Is that volume deleted when the container is stopped i.e. everything from the host machine for that volume is cleaned up? If not how do I configure that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, volumes are not deleted automatically (even if the container gets deleted) and you can list them using the `docker volume ls` command.

This could cause the presence of a possibly high number of dangling volumes (volumes not associated to any container) in the host. To remove them you can use this command for example:

```
docker volume rm `docker volume ls -q -f dangling=true`
```

(Took from here https://coderwall.com/p/hdsfpq/docker-remove-all-dangling-volumes)

Comment: In that case how do I configure to delete the volume when the container is terminated?

Comment: I don't think there is such an option. You have periodically to run  a command to delete so called dangling volumes. You could use this command for example: https://coderwall.com/p/hdsfpq/docker-remove-all-dangling-volumes

Comment: @ares - You can remove containers volume by using `rm -v` i.e `docker stop $CONTAINER_ID &&  docker rm -v $CONTAINER_ID`

Answer (score 3):

Adding to @Whites11 answer -

> No, volumes are not deleted automatically/by_default (even if the container gets
> deleted) and you can list them using `docker volume ls` command.

However, once your containers are stopped you can remove the volumes associated with them by using `rm -v` :

`$ docker stop $CONTAINER_ID && docker rm -v $CONTAINER_ID`

Manual -

> Usage:    docker rm [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [CONTAINER...]
>
> Remove one or more containers
>
> Options:
>
> -f, --force     Force the removal of a running container
> (uses SIGKILL)
>
> -l, --link      Remove the specified link
> -v, --volumes   Remove the volumes associated with the
> container